# How to query date in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Assuming I have the following table in oracle:

```
id|orderdatetime (date type)|foodtype (string type)
1|2013-12-02T00:26:00 | burger
2|2013-12-02T00:20:00 | fries
```

...
(assume there are many dates and times)

Assuming someone happened to have a date in mind (i.e. "2010-12-02T00:25:00").
even though there is no database entry with that specific time in there... 
is there some way to query the database such that I can get the row that has a date time that is closest to it without being ahead of the date in mind (ideally, it would be less than or equal to)?

(i.e. in this case, the sql query would return the row for "fries" and not "burger" because the time for burger is past the time the user had in mind despite the fact that the time for "burger" is closer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select x.* from (select id,orderdatetime,foods from orders
where orderdatetime <= YOURTIME order by orderdatetime desc)x
where rownum =1
```

Another would be:

```
select * from orders where orderdatetime = (select max(orderdatetime) from orders
where orderdatetime <= YOURTIME)
```

Comment: I dont think the max(id) would work. The dates are not ordered by ascending or decreasing order, essentially id's are random, but unique. Dates may be ordered randomly too.

Comment: You are right. I didn't pay attention to your data set. removed the second solution

Comment: Could you modify your answer such that it does not have that assumption? Or apply some sorting to orderdates?

Comment: @Damascusi Updated - ofcourse if there are multiple matching dates, you will get multiple rows in second scenario. Whereas the first would give you a random row from matching rows (probably the one with smallest id if it is the primary key and there are no other indices. But no gaurantee)

Comment: Something appears wrong, I tried sticking in "2010-12-02T00:25:00" in place of "YOURTIME" and I am getting a ORA00900 "Invalid SQL statement"

Comment: you should use the correct syntax there: orderdatetime <= TO_DATE('02/DEC/2010 00:25:00', 'dd/mon/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') or for easy copy pasting, <= TO_DATE('2010-12-02T0025;00','yyyy-mon-ddTHH24:MI:SS')

Comment: @Damascusi - are you still getting error? I updated the statements to explicit mention of columns. It should work.